# Doubt in vector product given magnitudes of unknown vectors and angle between them

Tags: vectors, cross-product

> Consider two vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$ whose components are not known. $|\vec a| = 3$, $|\vec b| = 2$ and an angle between them is $120^\circ$. Without assuming any particular components, calculate the magnitude of the vector product $|(\vec a − 3\vec b) \times (2\vec a + \vec b)|$.

I understand that when I just want to find the vector product given the above information I would use: $$|\vec a \times \vec b| = |\vec a||\vec b|\sin(\theta).$$

When I do this I end up with $|\vec a \times \vec b| = 3\sqrt 3$.  I am not sure whether I am supposed to do this and if I am where I go on from here to calculate $|(\vec a − 3\vec b) \times (2\vec a + \vec b)|$.

PS: This is my first time here so I am not sure how to add the little arrows above the terms to show they are vectors.

Comment: Use MathJax. That means you want to write something like `$\vec a\times\vec b$` to get $\vec a\times\vec b$.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for cross-product, we have $(\vec b × \vec a)=-(\vec a × \vec b)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
& (\vec a − 3\vec b) × (2\vec a + \vec b) \\ 
 & = (\vec a × 2\vec a) + (\vec a × \vec b) + (-3\vec b × 2\vec a) + (-3\vec b × \vec b) \\
 & = (\vec a × \vec b) + (-6)\color{blue}{(\vec b × \vec a)} \\
 & = (\vec a × \vec b) + (-6)\color{blue}{(-(\vec a × \vec b))} \\
 & = 7(\vec a × \vec b)
\end{align*}
$$

Does this help?

Comment: How would I use this in order to calculate the vector product |(⃗ −3⃗ )×(2⃗ +⃗ )|?

Comment: By using the formula you mentioned, $|\vec a \times \vec b| = |\vec a||\vec b|\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Oh of course.  Since I know the magnitude of |⃗ ×⃗|, I just multiply by 7.  Thank you!

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted.  My vote will not be displayed as my reputation is too low.  Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help!